# mysql get total values and total number from where clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a mysql query which will return the total number of values from a column and also the total number of values based on a where clause from the same column.

I have a table like this:

```
+------------------------+-------+
| color                  | code  |
+------------------------+-------+
| red                    |   200 |
| red                    |   202 |
| blue                   |   105 |
| yellow                 |   136 |
| green                  |   561 |
| red                    |   198 |
| blue                   |   414 |
| green                  |   11  |
| yellow                 |   600 |
| green                  |   155 |
| red                    |   865 |
| blue                   |   601 |
| green                  |   311 |
+------------------------+-------+
```

If I run this query:

```
select 
    color, 
    count(*) as count 
from colors 
where code > 0 && 
    code <= 500 
group by color 
order by count(*) desc;
```

I get this result which is great because it's almost what I want:

```
+------------------------+-------+
| color                  | count |
+------------------------+-------+
| red                    |     3 |
| green                  |     3 |
| blue                   |     2 |
| yellow                 |     1 |
+------------------------+-------+
```

What I also need returned is the total number of values in the column, so the result table would look like this.

```
+------------------------+--------------+-------+
| color                  | total        | count |
+------------------------+--------------+-------+
| red                    |            4 |     3 |
| green                  |            4 |     3 |
| blue                   |            3 |     2 |
| yellow                 |            2 |     1 |
+------------------------+--------------+-------+
```

So the total is the number of each value in the color column and count is the total amount which matches the where clause.

Thanks :)

Here is the link to SQLFiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/777f93/2

Comment: move the where clause to a case statement for the count and add a sum and you're done.

Comment: Also, SQL uses _AND_ instead of _&&_.

Comment: @Sloan Thrasher, according to the mysql docs both AND and && are correct. Same as || and OR. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use conditional aggregation to handle the counts and let the engine handle the total.

```
SELECT color
     , count(*) as Total
     , sum(case when code > 0 and code <= 500  then 1 else 0 end) as cnt 
FROM  colors 
GROUP BY color 
ORDER BY cnt desc;
```

Comment: Thanks xQbert, it works. I'll accept your answer as correct because although the other answers where also working you answered first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select color,
    count(*) as Total,
    sum(code > 0 and code <= 500) as count_0_to_500
from colors
group by color
order by count_0_to_500 desc
```

It uses the fact that true evaluates to 1 and false evaluates to 0 in MySQL.

It's basically what xQbert answered just without a case expression.

Comment: Yeah I try to do as much db agnostic stuff I can. But sometimes that suffers for performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` your query with another query, e.g.:

```
select color, count(*) as count , a.total
from colors JOIN (
    SELECT color, count(*) as `total` FROM colors GROUP BY color 
 ) a ON colors.code = a.color
where code > 0 && code <= 500 
group by color 
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You case use a case when statement to count only those items that meet your criteria. Like this:

```
Select 
color
, count(*) as total
, SUM(CASE WHEN code > 0 && code <= 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as Count
group by color order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using join query and table alias

```
    select t1.color,t1.total,t2.count 
FROM 
(select color, count(*) as total from colors group by color) t1,
(select color, count(*) as `count` from colors where `code` > 0 && `code` <= 500 group by color) t2
WHERE
t1.color=t2.color order by `count` desc;
```

Here is the link to SQLFiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/777f93/2